# Trigger with update

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

when I update the data in a table Form in the tables Book from the number of colbook must be subtracted -1.
please help to do this with a trigger

table Form

```
Create table Form (
idForm int not null primary key auto_increment,
date_of_issue date not null,
return_date date ,
idBook int not null,
Foreign key(idBook) references Book (idBook));
```

table Book

```
Create table Book (
idBook int not null primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(45) not null,
colBook int(11) null;
```

Filling a table Form

```
Insert into Form (idForm, date_of_issue)
Values(1, "2018-11-11");
```

Filling a table Book

```
Insert into Book (idBook, name, colBook)
Values(1, Garri Potter, 5);
```

table update request Form

```
update Form
set return_date = "2000-03-03"
where idBook = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a trigger on table "Form" as below:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER form_trigger_1 
AFTER INSERT ON form FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
update book
set colbook = colbook - 1
where idbook = old.idbook;
END
delimiter ;
```

Comment: only it takes not -1 and -2

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain it.

Comment: As you mentioned in question, whenever you update the FORM table the Book colBook column should substract with -1, so for example if the colBook having value 2 for any idBook in Book table. And you made update three times for the same idBook then your value will in negative. What you want really?